# Finding posts in certain categories which you haven't voted on (django-voting, django-categories)

Tags: python, django, django-voting

I have an app where Posts are split into various categories using the `django-categories` app, using hard-linking (ForeignKey to `categories.Category`).

I am also using the `django-voting` app to allow users to vote_up or vote_down certain posts.

Now I have a view where I require the latest posts from a list of `Categories` (the users category whitelist) which the user has NOT voted on and they are not his own posts. How do I go about getting these posts in the most efficient manner from the DB query load perspective.

Here is my Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True,
                               verbose_name='author', 
                               related_name='author_post')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length="240")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_images')
    up_votes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    down_votes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    category = models.ForeignKey('categories.Category')
```

Should I use RAW DB queries to get posts in reverse chronological order where the current logged in user hasn't voted and they aren't his own posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your db. If it's `PosgtreSQL`, you will be fine with subquery.

```
voted_already = (Vote.objects.filter(user=…, 
                                     content_type=…)
                             .values_list('object_id', flat=True))
not_voted = (Post.objects.filter(category__in=…)
                         .exclude(author=…, 
                                  pk__in=voted_already)
                         .order_by('-published'))
```

Comment: This looks similar to what I am already doing. I just wasn't quite sure this would scale:

`vlist = Vote.objects.filter(user=request.user)
 post = Post.objects.exclude(author_id=request.user.id, id__in=[item.object_id for item in vlist]).get()`

Comment: Your solution doesn't use subquery. You pass list of ids. If user has voted on big set of posts the list sent to db would be huge. My solution makes one query which involves subquery.

Comment: It should work, but I can not guarantee for subqueries in mysql being quick.

Comment: As your solution works (haven't tested impact of load on this) I am marking it as the correct answer. Will update here if I run into trouble as the load increases.